# CSS: relative positioninig of bottom right

Tags: html, css, css-position

The floating element has following structure:

```
<a>The_button</a>
<div style="position:absolute">
    <div style="position:relative" class="inner-box">
       Content
       Content
       Content
       Content
       Content
    </div>
</div>
```

The content of multiple inner-box controls has variable length, so the inner-box'es have variable height. I want to define CSS class .inner-box (without JavaScript) so that the **lower right** corner of the **inner-box** will be positioned in relation to **upper-left** corner of the link. Is this possible?

Target browsers are IE8+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari.

Links have always the same height and width.

Comment: You have an *id* "inner-box" but no *class* of the same name...

Comment: I synthesed this example on the fly. Let's change "id" to "class".

Comment: you want the lower-right corner of inner-box to Where? @Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>The only solutions I could come up with so far are:</strike>

http://jsfiddle.net/fmVz6/ - this requires a height and width to be defined on the "outer-box", not the inner-box (the inner must be absolutely positioned too).

Working on a second one at the moment ...

http://jsfiddle.net/fmVz6/1/ - this one does not require a height or width specified, it simply needs something inside the parent div (e.g. a space) to see the effect, otherwise the background doesn't appear.

Okay, to have it appear top-left of the link, http://jsfiddle.net/H5G8r/1/ (Requires some rearrangement of your HTML).

This one requires no width to be defined, and doesn't break the words onto multiple lines:
http://jsfiddle.net/H5G8r/2/

Take your pick :-)

Comment: Ok, actually, I want to position the popup in relation to link.

Comment: Yes. These are actually tooltips.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea, but backwards. The parent element needs `position: relative`, and the inner element `position: absolute`, since the inner element is absolutely positioned *relative to* its parent (technically, its `offsetParent`. Specifying `position: relative` on the parent makes it the `offsetParent` of all of its child elements).

Next: to align the top-left corner of the parent element with the bottom-right corner of the absolutely positioned child, specify `right: 100%; bottom: 100%` in the child's CSS. This puts the child <100% of the parent's width> away from the right edge of the parent, and <100% of the parent's height> away from the bottom.

#### HTML

```
<div class=outer-box>
    The Button
    <div class=inner-box>
    </div>
</div>​
```

#### CSS

```
.outer-box {
    position: relative;
}

.inner-box {
    position: absolute;
    /* align bottom-right with offsetParent's top-left */
    bottom: 100%;
    right: 100%;
    width: 100px; /* fixed width, else contents will shrink */
}
```

*Also in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanartecona/g344W/2/*

When you get those aligned, you may want to put another box inside the `.inner-box` and make it `position: relative` to make any position adjustments, like sliding it a fixed distance over the button, etc.